# Sorting text and numbers in Excel

Tags: excel, sorting

I got list of created ranges. What I want to do is sort them ascending by cell numbers they are refering to. I tried using sort option but all I came up with is to create my own sorting list...

**List of ranges:**

```
Column 1    Column 2
pp2dni2007  =szkolenia!$B$2:$E$33
pp2dni2010  =szkolenia!$B$273:$E$500
pp3dni2008  =szkolenia!$B$34:$E$83
pp3dni2009  =szkolenia!$B$84:$E$272
```

**Desired output:**

```
Column 1    Column 2
pp2dni2007  =szkolenia!$B$2:$E$33
pp3dni2008  =szkolenia!$B$34:$E$83
pp3dni2009  =szkolenia!$B$84:$E$272
pp2dni2010  =szkolenia!$B$273:$E$500
```

Comment: Oh my mistake, misread your question. I saw sorting and looked at your data. But why do you need to sort using the reference cell numbers? You are clearly using them in a logical order? `2007 = 2-33, 2008 = 34-83, 2009 = 84-272, 2010 = 273-500` So either way you will get the same result if you sort ascending/descending on `Column1`.

Comment: I think it will not go without VBA.

Comment: @t.thielemans I need to sort them, because when I click "use in formula -> paste -> paste list" it's not sorted + I gave you just example and it's not always so logical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I read loannis solution I came up with another solution to my problem ;)
Forgot to tell: column 2 data isn't importaat when comes to data but it is a hint on how to sort.

Okay, so it looks like that:

```
Column 1    Column 2
pp2dni2007  =szkolenia!$B$2:$E$33
pp2dni2010  =szkolenia!$B$273:$E$500
pp3dni2008  =szkolenia!$B$34:$E$83
pp3dni2009  =szkolenia!$B$84:$E$272
```

We got this data, so what is pain in here is this hard data "=szkoleni...".

To sort it out easy all is needed is to get rid of it.
 Using find&replace I am deleting "=szkolenia!$B$" part and then using it once again I am deleting rest of it ":*".

Now columns look like that:

```
Column 1    Column 2
pp2dni2007  2
pp2dni2010  273
pp3dni2008  34
pp3dni2009  84
```

Now it's just a case of simple sorting and voila! It can be easily used via macro too ;)

Thanks loannis, you were my inspiration ;)

Comment: Hi Iowak, thanks! Actually, I did try this method but rejected it because I thought that we cannot touch column 2. Glad i helped!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way (although a bit ugly).
Suppose a set up like this:

[image]

**Step 1:**

Place the cursor to `C1` and go to Formulas --> Define Name. Define the following name:
[image]

We need to use this function to get the formula of each cell in column `B` because we will sort based on this formula.

**Step 2:**

At cell `C1` enter and fill down:

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(GET_FORMULA,"=szkolenia!R",""),FIND("C",SUBSTITUTE(GET_FORMULA,"=szkolenia!R",""))-1)
```

broken down for convenience:

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(GET_FORMULA,"=szkolenia!R",""),
    FIND("C",SUBSTITUTE(GET_FORMULA,"=szkolenia!R",""))-1)
```

This basically returns the row number of the reference that is stored in `GET_FORMULA`.

**Step 3:**

Select columns `A`, `B` and `C` and sort based on column `C`:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Or with formulas:

[image]

**Notes:**

- The file has to be saved as macro-enabled in order to make the `GET_FORMULA` name work.
- I do not really like helper columns (like column `C` above) but in this case things would overcomplicate without it.

I hope this helps, although it is a really ugly solution..

Comment: Wow, you worked hard. When I read your solution I came with another one - I think easier one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sort&Filter

Reference Link

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sort-data-in-a-range-or-table-HP010073947.aspx

Comment: I am really interested so please reply. Where in this link you can find solution to my problem?